# Apply operations to groups in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am fairly new to the world of python and was wondering what the right approach would be to deal with this problem.

my dataframe looks something like this

```
import pandas as pd
frame={'id_var':[1,2,3,4,5],
         'category':['A','A','A','B','B'],
         'value':[10,20,30,40,50]}
data_frame=pd.DataFrame(frame)
```

I would like to calculate the percentage(of the column "value") of each row by the column "category"
How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IICU

```
data_frame['mean']=data_frame.groupby('category')['value'].apply(lambda x:((x/x.sum())*100).round(0))
data_frame
```

[image]